# Aspnet core mvc change default language on validation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently I am using standard jQuery validation and unobtrusive with data annotations, I'm trying to change the default error language.

I'm not trying to globalize the website but only to change the default error messages language or maybe default website language.

Is there a way to do it without overriding the error message in the model? Like

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "some localized validation text")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing all the responses from the ASP.NET web application to a certain language. This can be done by requesting the information in http header for the language you would want the response in. Detailed response for the same covered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338864/asp-net-web-api-model-is-valid-if-error-message-is-set-from-resources)